# YAML File Not Loading files

Tags: ros, node-handle, parameters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Folks,

I created my a YAML file. When I change the parameters in my YAML, then don't change in my code. I created the yaml inside my launch folder:

yaml_file.yaml

> min_user_distance: 0.9 ...

myClass.cpp

```
  class myClass
  {
     ros::NodeHandle nh_;

     public:
          myClass(int32_t user_id)
          : it_(nh_)
          {
              std::cout << "\n---------------------------\n";
              std::cout << "Object Parameters (CAMERA):\n---------------------------\n";
              //parameters from a YAML File
              nh_.param("min_user_distance", min_user_distance_, 0.9);
              std::cout << "min_user_distance = " << min_user_distance_ << "\n";
              nh_.param("max_user_distance", max_user_distance_, 1.8);
              std::cout << "max_user_distance = " << max_user_distance_ << "\n";
            }
   }
```

And this is how I load the yaml in my my_launch_file. launch

```
  <node name="my_node" pkg="my_package" type="my_node" output="screen">
      <rosparam file="$(find my_packge)/launch/yaml_file.yaml"/>
  </node>
```

When I change the value in the yaml file, the computer still prints 0.9 for the min_user_distance_ (which is the default value). Why does it always pick the default value?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240956/yaml-file-not-loading-files/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2016-08-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the documentation of the `<rosparam>` tag (http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/rosparam):

> The `<rosparam>` tag can be put inside
> of a `<node>` tag, in which case the
> parameter is treated like a private
> name.

So your code to get the parameters should use private names:

```
nh_.param("~min_user_distance", min_user_distance_, 0.9);
std::cout << "min_user_distance = " << min_user_distance_ << "\n";
nh_.param("~max_user_distance", max_user_distance_, 1.8);
std::cout << "max_user_distance = " << max_user_distance_ << "\n";
```

Alternatively, to create global parameters put the `<rosparam>` tag outside the `<node>` tag.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2016-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0